# What happens to cached DNS entry when DNS server entry is changed?

Tags: networking, dns

Suppose my local DNS server has cache of some Top Level DNS server's entry. Now, entry of the server's DNS record is changed. Now local cache value of DNS entry is false. How DNS resolves it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How DNS resolves it?

It doesn't - it waits until the "time to live" (TTL) on the entry in your cache has expired.